# How to access Nested JSON Data?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble displaying Nested JSON with ng-repeat.  I have a List of cars assigned to a person for a particular month.  If you search April you will get April data.  Click on the Name and it should populate Car section.  Here's [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NT3c7XRS6Plh3nEYZWx8?p=preview).  I have two functions one for the search button and the other for row click. Can someone tell me the proper way to push the nested car info?  Car info is in Results.

```
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.clickButton = function (enteredValue) {

    $scope.items = $scope.info;


    angular.forEach($scope.items[enteredValue], function (item, key) {
        $scope.results.push({
                 name: item.Name,
                 address: item.Address,
                 phone: item.Phone, 
                 status: item.Status,
                 cars:item.Cars
             });
     });
    };

   $scope.cars = [];

   $scope.clickButton2 = function () {

    $scope.rowItems = $scope.info.Cars;

    angular.forEach($scope.rowItems, function(car, key){
        $scope.cars.push({

            vehicleMake: car.Make,
                vehicleYear: car.Year
        });
         });
};
```

Comment: Please edit your post title into a specific question rather than a list of tags.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement this is by leveraging the `$index` scope variable set by `ngRepeat` (see [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)). This lets you pass the index of the result item to the controller method so that it knows which result to read the cars from:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results">
  <td ng-click='showCars($index)'>{{result.name}}</td>
  <td>{{result.address}}</td>
  <td>{{result.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{result.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

You can then use the index like this:

```
$scope.showCars = function(resultIndex) {
  $scope.cars = $scope.results[resultIndex].cars;
}
```

And finally display `$scope.cars` on the page:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th>Year</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <td>{{Make}}</td>
    <td>{{Year}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

One more thing: for array transformations such as the attribute lower-casing in your example code, consider using the [Array map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `angular.forEach()`. Here is an example:

```
$scope.cars = $scope.results[resultIndex].cars.map(function(car) {
  return {
    make: car.Make,
    year: car.Year
  };
};
```

Comment: I did not know about this mapping
$scope.results[resultIndex].cars.map(function(car)...
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Denis.  I went over the docs and modified the JS and I get resultIndex not found when creating the cars scope. http://plnkr.co/edit/HSpT2zjut33t8x5hI6U1?p=preview

Comment: The code at the plnkr link doesn't seem to work at all currently. I cannot even get any search results (404 error).